# End Date before Start Date Validation not working properly in Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, date, validation, custom-error-handling

I'm running into a problem where my end date validator is not performing as expected. It does display an error message - but only in cases where the end date is less than the **minimum** end date that's initialized at launch.

For example, I have a minimum end date of the current date + 1 month (2/24/2020), so the error will only appear under the Angular material input field when a date is selected before 2/24/2020. However, I want it to appear only when the date selected comes before the currently selected start date, as I have the date-picker disabled for any dates before the minimum start date. So proper behavior would be: user selects start date of 2/26/2020, and then an end date of 2/24/2020 --> error message should be thrown.

As a side note, in order to get the error message to appear, I have to manually type in the date to a date before the minimum end date.

I'm at a loss, so I'm just going to include the pieces of code that I think are relevant to this problem.

**Custom Error State Matcher:**

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
      return control.parent.invalid && control.touched;
    }
}
```

**Custom Validator:**

```
export function EndDateAfterSelectedStartDate(group: FormGroup) {
  const startDate = group.get('startDate').value;
  console.log('startDate:', startDate);
  const endDate = group.get('endDate').value;
  console.log('endDate:', endDate);

  if (endDate < startDate) {
    console.log('Invalid End Date!');
  }

  return group.get('endDate').value < group.get('startDate').value ? { EndDateBeforeSelectedStartDate: true } : null;
}
```

**HTML Template:**

```
 <div class="ui-g ui-fluid" formGroupName="date">
                <div class="ui-g-3"></div>
                <!--DATE: START AND END-->
                <mat-form-field class="ui-g-3" appearance="outline" floatLabel="auto"> 
                    <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="startDate" [min]="minStartDate" [max]="maxStartDate" [matDatepicker]="startPicker">
                    <mat-error>{{getErrorMessage('startDate')}}</mat-error>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #startPicker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field class="ui-g-3" appearance="outline" floatLabel="auto"> 
                    <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="endDate" [min]="minEndDate" [max]="maxEndDate" [matDatepicker]="endPicker">
                    <mat-error>{{getErrorMessage('endDate')}}</mat-error>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #endPicker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
                <p>End Date: {{addPersonForm.get('room').get('date').get('endDate').value}}</p>
                <br>
                <p>Start Date: {{addPersonForm.get('room').get('date').get('startDate').value}}</p>
                <div class="ui-g-3"></div>
            </div>
```

**Initialization of min / max dates on launch:**

```
this.minStartDate = new Date();
this.maxStartDate = new Date(this.minStartDate.getFullYear() + 2, this.minStartDate.getMonth(), this.minStartDate.getDate());
this.minEndDate = new Date(this.minStartDate.getFullYear(), this.minStartDate.getMonth() + 1, this.minStartDate.getDate());
this.maxEndDate = new Date(this.minEndDate.getFullYear() + 3, this.minEndDate.getMonth(), this.minEndDate.getDate());
```

**Initialization of Form Group:**

```
date: this.fb.group({
  startDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
  endDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
}, {validator: this.endDateAfter}),
```

**GetErrorMessage():**

```
  case 'endDate':
    // TODO: Right now, this error is thrown when end date goes below minEndDate
    if (room.get('date').hasError('EndDateBeforeSelectedStartDate')) {
      return 'End date must be after start date';
    }
    if (room.get('date').get('endDate').hasError('required')) {
      return 'End date / move-out must be provided';
    }
    break;
```

Comment: The validator you set on the form group is `this.endDateAfter`. You haven't posted the code of that function. You have posted the code of EndDateAfterSelectedStartDate, but that validator doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: Sorry, that's the validator used. Just change the names

Comment: EndDateAfter is just a reference to the actual validator